# Electric permittivity of quartz

Tags: crystals, electromagnetism

I'm performing an educational experiment on the piezoelectric effect in quartz, and it would be useful for me to know its electric permittivity.

I've been told that the quartz sample that I have is a cut 5° about one of its crystallographic axis, but it's not specified which axis that is. Is that ambiguity critical to the possibility of extracting the information I need from a table?

If there's any other information you need, please let me know in a comment. Thank you very much.